# Custom debugger based on windows api - debugging multithreaded process

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, debugging

In my debugger i set particular memory address to 0xCC (int3) and while execution one of the threads reaches this address. Exception is thrown. While handling exception i subtract IP register to point one instruction before 0xCC and replace 0xCC with original byte. I also set flag in thread context to throw exception after execute one instruction - I need to set back 0xCC byte.

**Problem:**
Code executes correctly but I realized that there possibly is a bug. After receiving exception I set back original byte and set flag in thread to back to the debugger just right after it executes one instruction (it lets me to set back int3). It sounds good but I have detected that **after original byte is executing another thread also executes this instruction without throwing exception (I think it can be related to threads switching).**

Comment: Well, that's certainly possible when more than one thread executes the same code.  Allowing the programmer to freeze and thaw a thread to give him a shot at debugging multi-threaded code is a standard debugger feature.

Comment: Ok, but could you describe me any mechanisms or algorithms to achieve it correctly ?